# strange output from ToExpression

Tags: symbols

I want to set constraints to my parameters, e.g., "m", but Mma gives nonsensical output. How could I avoid this phenomenon by using another but "equivalent expression"?
Or, is this just in my computer (i.e. a non-reproducible problem)?

case 1. output is as expected:

```
ToExpression[
 ToString[2.] <> ToString[">"] <> ToString["m"] <> ">=" <> 
  ToString[1.]]
```

> ```
> 2. > m >= 1.
> ```

case 2. output is unexpected:

```
ToExpression[
 ToString[0.10465923419974825] <> ToString[">"] <> ToString["m"] <> 
  ">=" <> ToString[-6.0857416503171394*^-6]]
```

> ```
> -60.8574
> ```

Comment: The `ToString[-6.0857416503171394*^-6]` is problematic. (`-6.08574 * 10 == -60.8574`) Use `Row[]` or `StringForm[]`.

Comment: But, maybe you'd like to use `Inequality` instead: `(#1 > m >= #2) &[0.10465923419974825, -6.0857416503171394*^-6]`

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says:

> ToString[expr]
>   gives a string corresponding to the printed form of expr in OutputForm.

The problem is with the `OutputForm` string of the exponent in the number:

```
ToString[-6.0857416503171394*^-6]
```

> ```
>            -6
> -6.08574 10
> ```

You can specify `InputForm` in this conversion with the second argument of `ToString`:

```
ToExpression[
 ToString[0.10465923419974825] <> ">" <> "m" <> ">=" <> 
  ToString[-6.0857416503171394*^-6, InputForm]
]
```

> ```
> 0.104659 > m >= -6.08574*10^-6
> ```

Note that you do not need `ToString` around things that are explicitly Strings.